# jquery mobile swipe not working for windows 8.1 desktop

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, swipe

I have used Jquery mobile v1.4.2 for my application. The application has a table with swipe left function.

1. Both google chrome and FireFox browsers did not work for mouse
   swipe. Both were fine for touch swipe. If I disable touch in my 
   machine then it works fine for mouse swipe.
2. My machine has IE 11. And it did not work for both touch and mouse
   swipe. Then I add below code to HTML file. After that IE worked fine
   for both touch and mouse swipe.

`<table id="activeQuestionList" style="-ms-touch-action: none;"></table>`

3. I use this web page in unity to show data and use coherentUI. Both
   touch and mouse swipe did not work in that unity application. but if
   I disable touch then application works fine for mouse swipe.

I need to fix this for touch and my machine has windows 8.1. Any idea to fix this?